# yii2 Как передать данные из одного метода контроллера в другой

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 2 action в одном контроллере. Первая форма - выбор чекбоксов. Вторая форма - вывод этих чекбоксов. Как передать значения из одной формы в другую, чтобы там уже переверять - отметил человек или нет.

Проблема в том, что данные не хранятся в БД. В модели создал кастомные public переменные и добавил в правила. В первой форме собираю данные ActiveForm, то есть я могу передать их в метод контроллер. Теперь как мне передать на другой экшн все мои поля ??

Первая форма и метод

```
public function actionExport($id)
    {
        return $this->renderAjax('/objects/export', ['model' => $this->findModel($id)]);
    }
```

и метод

```
 <?php $form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        'enableClientValidation' => false,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    ]) ?>

            <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="export"/> Все уведомления</label></p>
                <div id="checkbox_export">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_realtor')->checkbox() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_address')->checkbox() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_attributes')->checkbox() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_square')->checkbox() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_levels')->checkbox() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_price')->checkbox() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'export_info')->checkbox() ?>
                </div>
    <?php \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    <?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('PDF', ['pdf', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', 'target' => '_blank']) ?>

    <?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('Напечатать', ['pdf', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', 'target' => '_blank']) ?>

    <?php
    $script = <<< JS
    $("#export").change(function () {
    $("#checkbox_export input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
    JS;

    $this->registerJs($script);
    ?>
```

И вторая форма рендерит pdf файл

```
 public function actionPdf($id) {
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'content' => $this->renderPartial('/objects/pdf', ['id' => $id, 'model' => $model = $this->findModel($id)]),
            'options' => [
                'title' => 'Text',
                'subject' => 'Text'
            ],
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => ['Generated By: Krajee Pdf Component||Generated On: ' . date("r")],
                'SetFooter' => ['|Page {PAGENO}|'],
            ]
        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
    }
```

Данные на этот pdf в представлении /objects/pdf'.
Тут теперь нужно проверить, отмечен ли чекбокс - <

```
?php if($model->export_realtor): ?>
....
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: из экшена в экшен данные не передать, но между ними есть посредник-вид(view), вот через него и передавайте. т.е action1 вызывает форму ввода, из формы ввода вы вызываете action2 и передаете туда данные, а затем action2 выводит эти данные на форме вывода

Comment: У меня так и есть - на форме1 кнопка `<?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('PDF', ['pdf', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', 'target' => '_blank']) ?>` Обращаемся в action1, а с action1 уже идет рендер формы2.  Но вот как именно передать эти данные в action??

Comment: данные в http можно передать только get и post запросом